# AWS SFTP Transfer - Private Network/Subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, sftp

Is there a way to create AWS SFTP Transfer under a private subnet.
There are only two options `Public` and `VPC`.
VPC only allows for creating an endpoint that can be integrated with other AWS resources.
Can I create an AWS SFTP Transfer server in a private subnet and then connect it over the VPN etc to make sure it is secured and not exposed to the internet.
I hope I am clear with my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's just possible. Because sftp on vpc requires a private vpc end point. That makes the sftp accessible from vpc or on-premise via direct connect.

But I'm imagining few possible ways (I haven't tried this)

1. Ssh tunneling may work through the public instance
2. Connect to a proxy that is accessible via vpn , the proxy can then route the traffic via vpc end point

Comment: When using VPC it creates VPC Endpoint. How you will connect with a VPC Endpoint ?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking. I don't think we can. It's possible with a direct connect though.

Comment: But imagine, if we can setup a proxy server of some sort , we can reach to the proxy through VPN and through which we might be able to access the sftp ?

Comment: Thanks for the information , let me check with the solutions you suggested.